# Getting undefined for a list declared in Angular component level

Tags: arrays, angular, list, components

So, I have declared a list in a component level, like this:

```
export class CreateCompositeComponent implements OnInit {
...
controlActor: string[];
...
}
```

controlActor list gets filled in method 1):

```
this.controlActor = this.actorListResponse.concat(this.editedActorList);
```

And should be available in method 2) when patching form values:

```
this.form.patchValue({
     ...
      actor: this.controlActor,
     ...
    });
```

But, it is not available in method 2, I am getting undefined for value of `this.controlActor.`
How can I make the values of controlActor list that is filled in method 1, available in method 2?
Help appreciated.

Comment: At first glance, it would depend on which method is being called first. Check whether method 1 is being called first before method 2.

Comment: Actually, method 2 is being called first. Great advice, thank you. The question now is, what to do about it, without changing to much code?

Comment: Well it depends. If you could give more information or code snippets, we can figure it out. Might be a minor change, might be a lot of changes. It will depend entirely on what your Component looks like. But essentially, you need to figure out how method 1 could be called first.